# How to store data taken from a <form> in an HTML page to a local database?

Tags: html

I have a basic form in an HTML page which takes the `name` and `email` of an user and I want to store those details into a database. But, as far as I know javascript is a client side script so it can't directly connect to a database server. So, how do I store the data?

My code:

```
<form class="details">

        Full name: <input type="text" id="name" size=25><br>    
        E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" size=25><br><br>
    
</form>

<button id="button" onclick="submit()">Register</button>

<script>

     function submit(){// how do I connect to a database??}
</script>
```

Comment: You pass the data from JavaScript via AJAX to a server side environment, e.g. PHP, which can then put it in a database.

Comment: There are probably thousands of examples online and would depend on what language/framework you use for your backend.

Comment: If it works for you, you can do everything on the front end. Depending on how complex a solution you need, you can used [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or even something as simple as [`WebStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).